# What is difference between <extensionname>-backoffice-spring.xml and <extensionname>-spring.xml file Spring config in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

What is difference between -backoffice-spring.xml and -spring.xml file Spring config in Hybris?
(ant extgen with ybackoffice template)
What are the meanings and uses of these config files?
Example:
I define a bean:

```
<bean id="pieChartRenderer" name="pieChartRenderer" 
  class="com.hybris.demo.oms.renders.impl.DefaultPieChartRenderer">
    <property name="colors" >
        <list value-type="com.hybris.demo.oms.renders.ChartColor">
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Originally I defined in -spring.xml but not correct.
Then, I define bean to -backoffice-spring.xml =>OK

Answer (score 3):

-backoffice-spring.xml allows defining a bean in backoffice application context.

Backoffice application context is a child of the web application context of backoffice extension (which defines a web module).

-spring.xml files contain bean definitions of global application context. Each web module (web application) has its own web application context that is a child of the global context.

Beans defined in -backoffice-spring.xml are not visible to beans defined in -spring.xml since the later is a grand-parent application context of the first.